# Can't change destination in multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, path, fs, multer

When i upload my form (which just contains an image), the image goes in the root folder, but I would like it to go to /public/images. I have a separate routes.js file to handle routes. This is how I've set up multer (in my routes.js file).

```
var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({dest: '/public'});
```

The route for the POST request looks like this:

```
app.post('/upload', isLoggedIn, upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
        var file = __dirname + req.file.filename;
        fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(500);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                    filename: req.file.filename
                });
            console.log(file);
            }
        });
    });
```

, and the form itself looks like this (it's an ejs file):

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="profilepicture">Profile picture</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
                    <input type="submit" value="change profile picture">    
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing a wrong path in the `dest`, it's a relative path so it should be `dest: 'public/'` instead of `dest: '/public'`

Also, you are moving the file from the public folder by using `fs.rename` and the reason it is moved to outside the root folder is you are adding the root folder in the filename and not as a path :

```
var file = __dirname + req.file.filename;
```

should be :

```
var file = __dirname + '/' + req.file.filename;
```

or even better :

```
var file = path.join(__dirname, req.file.filename);
```

Overall, a working script with no need for the `fs.rename` :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'public/'});

app.post('/upload', isLoggedIn, upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    message: 'File uploaded successfully',
    filename: req.file.filename
  })
})
```